# How to mount multiple folders uboot bootargs

Tags: linux, boot, nfs, u-boot

I am trying to netboot a root file system of another linux. In this linux i have harcoded IP and MAC.
Its necessary to mount a specific /etc/network/interface.
After load kernel with tftp, i use

`set bootargs console=ttyO2,115200n8 root=/dev/nfs rootfstype=nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.11:/ ,vers=3 ro nfsaddrs=192.168.1.12`

I want to do a union mount, and i cant create a specific file system for each server becouse y have servers and limited space.

Its necesary use my root file system to another servers, but adding some specific configuration(using a specific /etc/networtk/interfaces for each server). I was looking here tldp.org/HOWTO/BootPrompt-HOWTO-3.html and `nfsroot` accept only one argument.

Maybe another way to use a dynamic not repeated file system?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by “multiple nfsroot path”? Do you want to do a union mount? To try several servers and pick the first that replies? Something else? Please explain your requirements.

Comment: Yes! I want to do a union mount, and i cant create a specific file system for each server with several servers. I need to use my root file system to another servers, but adding some specific configuration(using a specific /etc/networtk/interfaces for each server).
I was looking here http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/BootPrompt-HOWTO-3.html and only "The `nfsroot=' Argument"  accept only one argument.

Comment: I think you'll need an initramfs for that. `nfsroot` does an NFS mount, not a union mount.